# ELF executable SEGFAULTs when changing the p_vaddr

Tags: segmentation-fault, elf

Inspired by [this minimal ELF executable](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corkami/pics/master/binary/ELF.png) I created the following executable which works (and returns 42):

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 0300 0100 0000 5400 0008 3400 0000  ........T...4...
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3400 2000 0100 0000  ........4. .....
00000030: 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0008  ................
00000040: 0000 0008 6000 0000 6000 0000 0500 0000  ....`...`.......
00000050: 0000 0000 b801 0000 00bb 2a00 0000 cd80  ..........*.....
```

There is an ELF header here from `00` to `33`, a single program header from `34` to `53` and some code from `54` to `5F`.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8000054
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08000000 0x08000000 0x00060 0x00060 R E 0
```

If I now go ahead and change the p_vaddr and p_paddr from `0x8000000` to `0x1000` (or anything below `0x10000`) and adjust the entry point accordingly, I get an unexpected SEGFAULT. Here is the file after the adjustments:

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 0300 0100 0000 5410 0000 3400 0000  ........T...4...
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3400 2000 0100 0000  ........4. .....
00000030: 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000  ................
00000040: 0010 0000 6000 0000 6000 0000 0500 0000  ....`...`.......
00000050: 0000 0000 b801 0000 00bb 2a00 0000 cd80  ..........*.....
```

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1054
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00001000 0x00001000 0x00060 0x00060 R E 0
```

This is surprising to me since GCC produces working executables with the following program header:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00000034 0x00000034 0x00180 0x00180 R   0x4
  INTERP         0x0001b4 0x000001b4 0x000001b4 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00418 0x00418 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x00001000 0x00001000 0x00524 0x00524 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x00002000 0x00002000 0x00228 0x00228 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002ed4 0x00003ed4 0x00003ed4 0x00134 0x00138 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x002edc 0x00003edc 0x00003edc 0x000f8 0x000f8 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x0001c8 0x000001c8 0x000001c8 0x00060 0x00060 R   0x4
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0001ec 0x000001ec 0x000001ec 0x0001c 0x0001c R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x002008 0x00002008 0x00002008 0x00074 0x00074 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x002ed4 0x00003ed4 0x00003ed4 0x0012c 0x0012c R   0x1
```

Can someone explain to me why changing the p_vaddr makes my program SEGFAULT?

Answer (score 1):

> This is surprising to me since GCC produces working executables with the following program header

Look at the output from `readelf -h a.out` for the executable produced by GCC.
 You'll discover that its type is `ET_DYN`, *not* `ET_EXEC` (your binary is `ET_EXEC`) -- your GCC is (apparently) configured to produce PIE executables by default.

Unlike `ET_DYN`, `ET_EXEC` binary *must* be loaded at the linked-at address (zero in your case), and the kernel does not allow for anything to be loaded there.

Comment: Can you explain what the limitation is exactly? Why does loading at `0x10000` work but at `0x1000` doesn't? Does this depend on the kernel or the hardware? How do I pick the right number here?

Comment: @eyelash Loading at address `0x1000` should work (I think). It's hard to answer without a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, but you can start in `fs/binfmt_elf.c` to understand what restrictions the kernel places on the various addresses.

Comment: I have changed the example to be compatible with `xxd`. You should now be able to turn them back into executables with `xxd -r`.